# Разное время выполнения запроса для разных пользователей

Tags: sql-server

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: есть 2 пользователя (user1 и user2). Для каждого  из них запускаю один и тот же запрос. Время выполнения для первого 8 сек., для второго примерно 3 мин.
Запрос:

```
SELECT *     
FROM it_NCashOrd n 
WHERE (SUSER_NAME() IN (SELECT u.UserName FROM r_Users u WHERE u.EmpID IN (n.InitialID, n.EmpID)))
  OR ( EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 1
                        FROM it_RespPersonEmps rp 
                        LEFT JOIN r_Users u ON rp.UserID = u.UserID 
                        WHERE rp.RespPersonID IN (1,3,4,5,6,7) AND u.UserName = SUSER_NAME())) 
  OR (SUSER_NAME() IN ('user3'))
```

Поле "UserName" является индексируемым уникальным. Если убираю его из индекса, тогда для первого и второго пользователя запрос выполняется одинаково быстро. Есть также другие индексы, однако они не влияют на производительность.

Comment: Смотрите план выполнения (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-and-save-execution-plans?view=sql-server-2017). Не видя вашей БД сказать практически не реально. оптимизатор учитывает массу факторов, таких как количество записей с конкретными значениями ключей, размер таблиц, селективность индексов. И он периодически ошибается. Индекс убирать не обязательно, можно в запросе заключить поле в какую нибудь функцию, тогда оптимизатор не сможет использовать индекс по этому полю. Так же стоит переписать запрос по другому

Comment: Попробуйте значение функции *SUSER_NAME* взять в переменную - `DECLARE @userName nvarchar(128) = SUSER_NAME();` (тип переменной желательно согласовать с типом столбца в таблице), и использовать переменную в запросе вместо функции. Функция *SUSER_NAME* недетерминированная, это может ограничивать оптимизатор при выборе стратегии оптимизации. Да, запрос стоит попробовать переписать.

Comment: В дополнение к рекомендациям коллег, дополните запрос OPTION (RECOMPILE), это позволит избежать прослушивания параметров.

Comment: Похоже, что нашел причину: для второго пользователя медленее выполняется SUSER_NAME(). Изменил запрос подставив вместо SUSER_NAME() имя пользователя и отработало на ура. Кстати, способ с использованием переменной которую предложил i-one тоже не помог. Буду капать глубже.